# Cumulative Sum of a Vector - Syntax

Tags: matlab, syntax

I am trying to resolve why the following Matlab syntax does not work.

1. I have an array 
   A = [2 3 4 5 8 9...]
2. I wish to create an indexed cumulative, for example
   s(1) = 2; s(2)=5, s(3)=9; ...  and so on

Can someone please explain why the following does not work

```
x = 1:10
s(x) = sum(A(1:x))
```

The logic is that if a vector is created for s using x, why would not the sum function behave the same way?  The above returns just the first element (2) for all x.

Answer (score 4):

For calculating the cumulative sum, you should be using `cumsum`:

```
>> A = [2 3 4 5 8 9]

A =

     2     3     4     5     8     9

>> cumsum(A)

ans =

     2     5     9    14    22    31
```

The issue is that `1:x` is `1` and that `sum` reduces linear arrays.  To do this properly, you need a 2d array and then sum the rows:

```
s(x)=sum(triu(repmat(A,[prod(size(A)) 1])'))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two questions, really. One is - how do I compute the cumulative sum. @SouldEc's answer already shows how the `cumsum` function does that. Your other question is

> > Can someone please explain why the following does not work

```
x = 1:10
s(x) = sum(A(1:x))
```

It is reasonable - you think that the vector expansion should turn

```
1:x
```

into

```
1:1
1:2
1:3
1:4
```

etc. But in fact the arguments on either side of the colon operator must be scalars - they cannot be vectors themselves. I'm surprised that you say Matlab isn't throwing an error with your two lines of code - I would have expected that it would (I just tested this on Freemat, and it complained...)

So the more interesting question is - how *would* you create those vectors (if you didn't know about / want to use `cumsum`)?

Here, we could use `arrayfun`. It evaluates a function with an array as input element-by-element; this can be useful for a situation like this.  So if we write

```
x = 1:10;
s = arrayfun(@(n)sum(A(1:n)), x);
```

This will loop over all values of x, substitute them into the function `sum(A(1:n))`, and voila - your problem is solved.

But really - the right answer is "use `cumsum()`"...

Comment: Many thanks.  The key hole in my knowledge was that the arguments on either side of the colon must be scalar.  I should have known that!  I am using Matlab 2011a and it didn't complain, which is possible the reason I did not ping to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing is 
s(1:10)= sum(A(1:[1,2,3...10]))
 what you should do is

```
for i=1:10
    s(i)=sum(A(1:i))
end
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I actually implemented it using the for loop, but I asked the question because I had an intuitive feeling that there was probably a better way.

Comment: try using i=1:10; s(i)=sum(A(1:i)); :)